# Lexmark 4300 series printer

Tags: printing, lexmark

There is no driver for my 4300 series lexmark printer, I tried to use the program Wine to install the driver but this did not work. Can anyone take a look at this problem?

Comment: Hi Marcel, welcome to AskUbuntu. Lexmark printers are problematic in general, most models are not usable from Ubuntu. The only way you might succeed is by installing the software in a Windows virtual machine and access it from the Ubuntu host.

Answer (score 0):

Lexmark does provide Linux drivers including for Debian/Ubuntu. They have a manual here: http://www.lexmark.com/publications/pdfs/print_drivers/en/ug.pdf. It's all quite straightforward.

P.S. Wine is for running applications (=in the user space), you can't use it to make Windows drivers run under Linux: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ

EDIT. I quoted from my experience of setting up a laser Lexmark on OpenSUSE, however it seems their inkjet printers are much less Linux-friendly. So I could be wrong.